# Centering an widget in a row by height in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm sorry for my bad english

I just want to center the icon widget on the row. How can I do that?

[here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcoE6.png)

[what i want is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPNl6.png)

here is my code

```
Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 40.r,
                    //backgroundImage: AssetImage(_imagaPath),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0.w),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        TextWidget(
                          "Good morning",
                          fontSize: 12.sp,
                          color: silver,
                          fontWeight: semiBold,
                        ),
                        TextWidget(
                          "John",
                          fontSize: 20.sp,
                          fontWeight: bold,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Spacer(),
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                    child: const Icon(Icons.add),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap your widget with `Center` like:

```
 Center(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.yellow,
              child: const Icon(Icons.add),
            ),
          ),
```

the output would look like:

[image]

Comment: I thought I had done this before and failed, but now it has. Thank you so much <3

Answer (score 0):

maybe you just make this    `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start`,
to
`crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center`, for first Row